# PHP - AJAX - mysql - Unable to insert data into database (works perfect when not using AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have this "register users" file in which I have a form, I'll simplify in here what I have:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="user" class="control-label">User </label>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" id="user"  value="" required=""/>
    <label for="user" class="control-label">Password1 </label>
    <input type="text" name="password1" class="form-control" id="password1"  value="" required=""/>
    <label for="user" class="control-label">Password2 </label>
    <input type="text" name="password2" class="form-control" id="password2"  value="" required=""/>
    <button type="button" value="signUp" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick="register()">Sign up!</button>
```

As you can see, there is an event in there, in a JS file. This file has all the vaidations of the inputs and it works just fine (I don't think it's relevant, so I won't post it). It also has the AJAX call to the PHP file that will insert the data into the database.

```
 function register(){

 if(validationRegister()){
        $.ajax({

                url: "http://localhost/myProject/extras/processSignUp.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {"user": user,
                       "password": password,
                       "password2": password2,
                       },
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {    
                    console.log("Processing...");
                },
                success: 
                      function(data){
                        if(data == "Registered"){
                           window.location.href = "http://localhost/myProject/index.php";
                        }else{
                           window.location.href = "http://localhost/myProject/signUp.php";
                        }
                    }

    });

}else{
    alert("Incorrect data");
}
```

}

And this is the PHP file:

```
 <?php

    include_once "connection.php"; --> this has all the data for the connection to the database 

    if($_POST['user'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '' || $_POST['password2'] == ''){ 
        echo 'Fill all the information'; 
    }else{ 

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `user`'; 
        $rec = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
        $verify_user = 0; 

        while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)){ 
            if($result->user == $_POST['user']){ 
                $verify_user = 1; 
            } 
        } 

        if($verify_user == 0){ 
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']){ 
                $user = $_POST['user']; 
                $password = $_POST['password'];  
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user (user,password) VALUES ('$user','$password')";
                mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

                echo "Registered"; 
            }else{ 
                echo "Passwords do not match"; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            echo "This user has already been registered"; 
        }
    } 

?>
```

The PHP code, works great when used on its own (it used to be at the beginning of the form file, surrounded by if($_POST['submit']){}) But now I want to use it in a separate file, and use AJAX, and I'm unable to register a user :/ the value of data is never "Registered"... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Log `data`, what is it? You are open to SQL injections and should be hashing your passwords.

Comment: **Look at your code** Specifically `if($_POST['user'] == '' or $_POST['password']){ ` ?? `or $_POST['password']` WHAT

Comment: @chris85 yes, I know, but I'm learning and just starting the project, will add more things soon. data is what the AJAX call receives. I actually have lots of trouble dealing with that, and suspect much of the problem is in that part :/

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi, yes, sorry for that. As I've mentioned I've edited the code to the most important part to illustrate my problem. While editing I've must had cut part of code that had to be there, I didn't realize. Will edit the post.

Comment: Be careful summarising! We can only help with what we can see

Comment: I mean what is the actual value of it `console.log(data);` perhaps you have a new line in there, or some whitespace?

Comment: @chris85 oh, I see now, I didn't think of inspecting it with a console.log().. I seems that the $con (a variable for the connection) is undefined. I took a look at it, and the problems was that the connection file was in some other folder, which I forgot to add to the include url. That fixed it! :D Thank you very much for very kind and helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please never run this code in a live environment, your code is open to SQL injection and you NEED to hash passwords.

This line:

```
if($_POST['user'] == '' or $_POST['password']){
```

Looks to be your issue. You want to be testing `$_POST['password']` somehow, like `$_POST['password'] == ''` or `!isset($_POST['password'])`.

Your logic is also horribly constructed, you may want to go look at a few tutorials. e.g. why are you fetching ALL your users just to test if one exists, do that logic in the SQL code itself to avoid fetching an entire table for no reason.

Comment: hi, thanks, but the problem after all was a missing folder from a url, so the connection variable was undefined. Also, I'm working with someone else on this, so part of that logic was actually not mine, I'm trying to adapt to it.